# Cydia has crashed and my device is protecting it

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

My iPhone is jailbroken and it crashed and it says cydia is causing the problem and my device is protecting it or something. I can't even unlock my iPhone.

Comment: When explaining your problem, it's always a good idea to quote what exactly is written in an error message, both to help people understand what the problem is and for other people to search for a solution to the same problem. Please edit your question to include what the actual error referring to Cydia Substrate protecting the device is informing you of.

Answer (score 1):

Cydia has not crashed, Cydia Substrate has protected you against a tweak which is crashing by putting your device in Safe Mode. To exit safe mode, tap Restart on the dialog which is shown when unlocking the device. If safe mode is activated next time the device resprings, then the problem is caused by a tweak which needs to be uninstalled. Open Cydia and uninstall any recent tweaks to attempt to fix the problem. If you do not know which tweak is causing the crash, you can install Crash Reporter which will find suspects to a symbolicated crash log.

Comment: It doesn't have that option

Comment: @Thabokubeka This is why I suggest you edit your question to add what the error message is actually saying as I can't speculate any further as to what you're seeing.

Comment: it says we apologize for the incovinece but springboard has crashed mobilesubstrate/did not/cause this problem:it has protected u from it...

Comment: @Thabokubeka Yes, therefore you need to unlock your device and tap Restart. You say you can't unlock it, but can you expand as to why this is? The error *is* the one that I inferred from your limited generalisation and therefore my answer still applies.

Comment: Thats all it said and I had recently dropped my phone in da water but it was working fine and stuff then the this hot temp adviser came. On cause it said my phone was to hot and in da morning it turned off I think and rebooted and never unlocked again

Comment: And it doesn't even show me the time

Comment: @Thabokubeka Water immersion, failing hardware sensors, non-standard OS (jailbreak plus tweaks) - this is going to be hard to troubleshoot unless you put the device into firmware recovery and get back to stock iOS and then make sure the hardware is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet to fix the software is to restore it through iTunes, restore from backup, then re-jailbreak it. This won't address any water damage issues though...